# OpenWRT dnsmasq: possible DNS-rebind detected

Tags: openwrt, dnsmasq

I have a problem since I use a new router (`TP-Link WDR4300 + OpenWRT BarrierBreaker`) and in the `System log` is full of this periodically:

```
<Timestamp> dnsmasq[2524]: possible DNS-rebind attack detected: 4385410-0-3084195388-824858262.ns.183-213-22-60-ns.dns-spider.ffdns.net
```

I use my ISP's DNS (`Telekom Hungary, IPv4 DNS`) but I've tried Google's too (`8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` too), but there is this issue.

I can reach my router from `WAN` (via `DDNS` (`duckdns`)), may it possible that this is the source of my problem?

I've tried to search `DNS-rebind attack` and so in OpenWRT topics but sadly I can't found anything useful there.

There is any workaround to prevent those `bots` to `rebind`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was a port restriction on port `53`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like dnsmasq is reachable from the internet.  This allows DNS scanners to attempt rebind attacks.  Check your firewall configuration.  This particular server appears to be a research server, although I would expect only a few attempts from such a server.

Generally you want a mostly closed configuration on the internet interface with only the services you need enabled.  DNS is usually not one of the services you want to enable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @BillThor.

I've ran `netstat -pln` and the result is: [HERE](http://prohardver.hu/dl/upc/2016-07/174343_router_netstat_2_png.jpg).

As you can se somewhy the `dnsmasq` opens the port but I don't know why and don't know how to close that port (I've made port restrict, but the port is still open, just not forward it).